Decoding Google News Redirect URLs
I am currently working on a project that involves crawling news articles from Google News via RSS feeds. After gathering these news articles, my next task is to convert the provided Google News redirect URLs into their original URLs. Google News typically provides redirect links like this:
https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMivAFBVV95cUxQQ2J4MGNnRjR2SzdKM2hjQzdkVV83cE8xU3BYN0RhbVhGWTZfXzFrcWMxZnpONmFrbE53ZEVXVy1CSnZZT1ZPQl9UblljRHdBelRJdEdXLUhBajFQMlRidEZ1dUtqY0U0dXI5R2tnWU9uT1cteGg2UTVtNU9oaU1TRGJuLXAxa3A2cnhqeURaUG1YdjRwZk9IZ0VFaG1ON01xLVVPVVYwZmMtSmFva09vZ2JicVFCal91UVNsTA?oc=5
Initially, I used the "requests" library to retrieve the final URLs. However, I later discovered that these URLs could be decoded using the "base64" method, which worked perfectly until Google recently changed the structure of their URLs, rendering my code obsolete.
Here is my current code:
import base64
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def decode_google_news_url(source_url):
    url = urlparse(source_url)
    path = url.path.split('/')
    if (
        url.hostname == "news.google.com" and
        len(path) > 1 and
        path[len(path) - 2] == "articles"
    ):
        base64_str = path[len(path) - 1]
        decoded_bytes = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(base64_str + '==')
        decoded_str = decoded_bytes.decode('latin1')

        prefix = bytes([0x08, 0x13, 0x22]).decode('latin1')
        if decoded_str.startswith(prefix):
            decoded_str = decoded_str[len(prefix):]

        suffix = bytes([0xd2, 0x01, 0x00]).decode('latin1')
        if decoded_str.endswith(suffix):
            decoded_str = decoded_str[:-len(suffix)]

        bytes_array = bytearray(decoded_str, 'latin1')
        length = bytes_array[0]
        if length >= 0x80:
            decoded_str = decoded_str[2:length+1]
        else:
            decoded_str = decoded_str[1:length+1]

        return decoded_str
    else:
        return source_url

# Example usage:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    source_url = 'https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMivAFBVV95cUxQQ2J4MGNnRjR2SzdKM2hjQzdkVV83cE8xU3BYN0RhbVhGWTZfXzFrcWMxZnpONmFrbE53ZEVXVy1CSnZZT1ZPQl9UblljRHdBelRJdEdXLUhBajFQMlRidEZ1dUtqY0U0dXI5R2tnWU9uT1cteGg2UTVtNU9oaU1TRGJuLXAxa3A2cnhqeURaUG1YdjRwZk9IZ0VFaG1ON01xLVVPVVYwZmMtSmFva09vZ2JicVFCal91UVNsTA?oc=5'
    print(decode_google_news_url(source_url))

And here is the response it provides:
AU_yqLPlNi5OTSra2IojECSi6Re8V2vptxwGVgYs8W1h9EAJuVMrZJI5XFkdXW75qsHvUINr5X7dMwyGg-M5gtxmgzDepwKY5IAn6TsUaOfSl8AqnHIR5YE
Thank you for your help!
How can I resolve this issue? Is there an approach to update my code to detect the new URL structure and provide the final URL?

It's worth noting that the string contains no special characters at all.  Almost every base64 of that length would have one of the specials.  Thus, this might be something like a base62.

In the new redirect method of Google News, the string within the URL, when base64 decoded, I thought it seems to be a server-side identifier. Therefore, it's not possible to extract the original URL from the redirect URL.
By searching for '.send' in the source code of the redirect page, you'll likely find the corresponding method. The body of this overridden 'send' method is probably located in the JavaScript file gstatic.com//mss/boq-dots//js/.../m=...
The request is structured like this:
f.req=[[["Fbv4je","["garturlreq",[["en","US",["FINANCE_TOP_INDICES","WEB_TEST_1_0_0"],null,null,1,1,"US:en",null,540,null,null,null,null,null,0,null,null,[1717597091,738001000]],"en","US",1,[2,3,4,8],1,0,"658136446",0,0,null,0],"CBMivAFBVV95cUxQQ2J4MGNnRjR2SzdKM2hjQzdkVV83cE8xU3BYN0RhbVhGWTZfXzFrcWMxZnpONmFrbE53ZEVXVy1CSnZZT1ZPQl9UblljRHdBelRJdEdXLUhBajFQMlRidEZ1dUtqY0U0dXI5R2tnWU9uT1cteGg2UTVtNU9oaU1TRGJuLXAxa3A2cnhqeURaUG1YdjRwZk9IZ0VFaG1ON01xLVVPVVYwZmMtSmFva09v22JicVFCal91UVNsTA"],null,"generic"]]]&at=AHVjzVkf4a4_gUrrCQuBIfcGdqNJ:1722763169526&

The response looks something like this:
)]}'

246
[["wrb.fr","Fbv4je","["garturlres","https://www.lopinion.ma/Les-deputes-adoptent-a-l-unanimite-une-proposition-de-loi-sur-le-Code-des-assurances_a56510.html\",1]",null,null,null,"generic"],["di",32],["af.httprm",32,"4671226804392012087",36]]
25
[["e",4,null,null,282]]"


I found someone else who was reverse-engineering batchExecute https://gist.github.com/huksley/bc3cb046157a99cd9d1517b32f91a99e
